# Author custom fields post meta, the code?

Tags: author, custom-field, user-meta

If I wanted to get a custom field of the current user I would use something like this.

`<?php echo get_user_meta($user_info->ID,'address_line_2',true);?`>

This time however I want the author so I tried multiple version of the following to no avail.

```
<?php 
$thisauthorID = get_the_author_ID();

echo get_the_author_meta($thisauthorID,'address',true)
        ;?>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_author_meta()` != `get_user_meta()`.
Change to:
`echo get_the_author_meta('address', $thisauthorID);`

Comment: humm - not sure i get the difference. get_the_author_meta() defaults to the current user, unless the second parameter is defined. Where as get_user_meta(id) means the user id must be passed in. Is that the main difference?

Comment: I think get the author will default to the author of the current post object, not the current user. That's why you have to pass current user's id.